# Error using Drush and Civi API when adding data to a custom field with multi-select data

Tags: api, drush

I have been trying to create contacts data using Drush and the CiviAPI.  I get an error when I try to add data to a multi-select field despite using exactly the same syntax that the API explorer gives me.

I have a custom field (machine name: custom_10) that takes up to 5 options. As an example, If I use the API explorer to create the following output, I get this:

```
drush cvapi Contact.create contact_type="Individual" contact_sub_type="MySubType" custom_10=[1,2,3] first_name="John" last_name="Doe"
```

Executing this though the API explore works fine, but if I copy the drush line and execute it, the array data for custom_10 causes an error:

```
Array
(
    [error_field] => custom_10
    [error_code] => 2001
    [entity] => Contact
    [action] => create
    [is_error] => 1
    [error_message] => '1,2,3' is not a valid option for field custom_10
)
```

executing a single option with custom_10=1 will work fine.  I have tried various different syntax but cannot get it to take.  Has anyone else had this issue with the Drush approach for arrays in Custom fields?

I have no issues adding anything else Contact wise including chaining for additional emails.  It is just fields that have arrays of data.

Comment: How about passing array in JSON format?

Comment: Pradeep - you are absolutely right, my initial comment below was wrong and I have deleted it.  I have now tried this and amended my output to pass in JSON arrays and it seems to work OK.  Many thanks for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're running into the same problem I've documented on Gitlab as [issue #298](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/298) - basically, API Explorer doesn't return correct code when you need to pass in an array.